# how to call a jquery plugin for sticky kit

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky

I know this is probably an easy peasy baby question, but when you don't know you don't know :)

I've been trying to install the jquery plugin, but I do not know how to "Just call stick_in_parent on the elements you want to be stuck inside of their parent. " (quote from the sticky kit web page)

I added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.sticky-kit.js"></script>
```

after thejquery link

and I tried (in a desperate blind stab in the dark)...

```
<script>
function () {
$(".navtop").stick_in_parent()
}
</script>
```

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can use separate id's for each element you want to be stuck in their parent at the function call could look something like this placed inside of your script tag

```
 $(document).ready(function(){


 $("#first-element","#second-element").stick_in_parent();





});
```

Now the class selector .navtop you used in your example will select all elements with the 
class .navtop which might cause a problem if you only want certain elements to become stuck in their parent.

Comment: This answered my question and got it to work by adding $(document).ready(function(){ thank you so much!